# Creating a static factory

Tags: java, processing

I am making an application to control a serial attached printer and I want to provide a static factory method `PrinterLocator.FindPrinters()` that will return an array of the available printers connected to my system.

As an example, the Serial library provides `Serial.list()` which is a static method returning an array of strings corresponding to the ports available in my system.  I am trying to create something similar, but I am getting an error "No enclosing instance of type SLPDriver is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type SLPDriver"

What is the correct way to implement this design pattern?

SLPDriver:

```
SerialPrinter myPrinter;


void setup()
{
  SerialPrinter[] availablePrinters = PrinterLocator.FindPrinters();
  if(availablePrinters.length > 0)
  {
    myPrinter = availablePrinters[0];
  }
}

void draw()
{
}
```

SerialPrinter:

```
import processing.serial.*;

static class PrinterLocator
{
  static final int baudRates[] = {2400, 4800, 9600, 19200, 38400, 57600, 115200};
  static final int baudCount = baudRates.length;

  static SerialPrinter[] FindPrinters()
  {
    SerialPrinter[] foundPrinters, tempPrinters;
    foundPrinters = new SerialPrinter[0];
    String[] foundPorts = Serial.list();
    int numPorts = foundPorts.length;
    int numPrintersFound = 0;
    if(numPorts <= 0) return foundPrinters;

    SerialPrinter testPrinter;

    tempPrinters = new SerialPrinter[numPorts];
    for(int i = 0; i < numPorts; i++)
    {
      for(int b = 0; b < baudCount; b++)
      {
        testPrinter = new SerialPrinter("test", foundPorts[i], baudRates[b]);
        if(testPrinter.IsValid())
        {
          tempPrinters[numPrintersFound] = testPrinter;
          numPrintersFound++;
          break;
        } 
      }
    }

    if(numPrintersFound > 0)
    {
      foundPrinters = new SerialPrinter[numPrintersFound];
      for(int i = 0; i < numPrintersFound; i++)
      {
        foundPrinters[i] = tempPrinters[i];
      }
    }

    return foundPrinters;
  }

}

class SerialPrinter
{
  //Members
  private Serial myPort;
  private String printerName;
  private boolean valid;
  private String portName;
  private int baudRate;

  public SerialPrinter()
  {
    this("","",0);  
  }

  public SerialPrinter(String name, String port, int baud)
  {
    printerName = name;
    Configure(port, baud);
  }

  public boolean IsValid()
  {
    return valid;
  }

  public boolean Configure(String port, int baud)
  {
    print("Configuring Printer ");
    print(port);
    print("@");
    print(baud);
    print(": ");
    try
    {
      myPort.stop();
      myPort = null;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}

    portName = port;
    baudRate = baud;
    try
    {
      myPort = new Serial(this, port, baud);
      myPort.clear();
      myPort.write(0xA5);
      int timeout = millis() + 1000;
      while((millis() < timeout) && (myPort.available() == 0)) { }
      if(myPort.available() > 0)
      {
        int inByte = myPort.read();
        if(inByte == 0xC9)
        {
          valid = true;
        }
        else
        {
          valid = false;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        valid = false;
      }   
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      valid = false;
    }
    if(valid)
    {
      println("[OK]");
    }
    else
    {
      println("[ERR]");
    }
    return valid;
  }
}
```

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: `testPrinter = new SerialPrinter("test", foundPorts[i], baudRates[b]);` in SerialPrinter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No enclosing instance of type SLPDriver is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type SLPDriver

The error indicates that `SerialPrinter` is an inner class of `SLPDriver`.

You either need to change the class declaration to static:

```
static class SerialPrinter
{
    ...
```

Or if it's supposed to be inner, you need to use an `SLPDriver` instance to create a `SerialPrinter`:

```
someSLPDriver.new SerialPrinter(...)
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

---

The `Serial` constructor appears to need an instance of `PApplet`. The instantiation expression should really give you an error too because `this` refers to the `SerialPrinter`, not the `PApplet`.

Something you could try is like the following:

```
...

static class PrinterLocator {
    ...

    static SerialPrinter[] FindPrinters(SLPDriver context) {
        ...

        ... = context.new SerialPrinter(...);
    }
}

class SerialPrinter {
    ...

    public boolean Configure(...) {
        ...

        ... = new Serial(PApplet.this, ...);
    }
}
```

When you call `FindPrinters` within the context of the applet, you need to call it like

```
... = PrinterLocator.FindPrinters(this);
```

Comment: The API Documentation for the Serial Library indicates the constructor for Serial requires a reference to `this` which does not exist within the context of a static class. https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial.html Also, I am not intending to create a static class, just a static factory method.

Comment: I edited to clarify. But you need to do one of the things I suggested. You can't really have your cake and eat it too here. You should also really read the tutorials I linked to. A static class is just like a top-level class. Note that if you declare a top-level class in Processing it's actually inner because the "global" context is within an instance of the applet.